# ERROR 1064 (42000): SQL sintax error

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched on many topics here, no one talks about this error like my case.

First of all, I want to make a database dump into a cientific articles system. It's usually done through the site/phpmyadmin on the import tab, but in my case, the sql file is too big. I'm trying to import it with this command:

**mysql -u root -p ojs3 < localhost.sql**

This is the result:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 11737232:
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '201b
> ,
> (125409, 3099, 170),
> (125409, 3099, 171),
> (125409, 1561, 172),
> (125409, 3' at line 1391**

I've opened the file using **vi**. There's nothing wrong in the code, you can see for yourself:
[at the 125409, ... subjects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYoJu.jpg)

Line 11737232:

**INSERT INTO `article_search_object_keywords` (`object_id`, `keyword_id`, `pos`) VALUES**

Thanks already for your help !!
Peace

Comment: there's no php or enough code to support the question

Comment: Look for `201b` in your file. That's what's throwing the error. I'm guessing it should probably be `201)`, considering your data.

Comment: There wasn't the correct line. 201b was the problem, I don't know how it was there, but I just deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is something wrong with the code, otherwise you would not see the error.

You snapshot doesn't show the part mentioned in the error message. search for

```
201b,(
```

And look before and after that for some simple syntax error like a missing quote, missing comma, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That 201b was the problem, I just deleted it.
The problem now is this:

**ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 386: Unknown column 'journal_id' in 'field list'**

This is the line 386, 387 and 388 lines:

**INSERT INTO `announcement_types` (`type_id`, `journal_id`, `type_name`) VALUES
(30, 18, 'text'),
(2, 5, 'text2'),**

all the atributes seem to be correct.